# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32'). Any advice?

Tags: python, pca, validation

The error below presented itself when attempting to assemble a PCA.

My code:

```
  is_float = X.dtype.kind in 'fc'
    if is_float and (np.isfinite(_safe_accumulator_op(np.sum, X))):
        pass
    elif is_float:
        msg_err = "Input contains {} or a value too large for {!r}."
        if (allow_nan and np.isinf(X).any() or
                not allow_nan and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
            type_err = 'infinity' if allow_nan else 'NaN, infinity'
            raise ValueError(
                    msg_err.format
                    (type_err,
                     msg_dtype if msg_dtype is not None else X.dtype)
            )
```

The error:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Any help or advice would be deeply appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The error seems to suggest you have some values that cannot be handled by the code, have you checked if you have missing values of infinity values in your dataset?